# How to handle computationally heavy objects creations

Tags: android, service, binding

In the app I'm working on, there is a background task which does some heavy work. This task needs to be executed often, and involves a computationally heavy creation of some objects. Now, I understand that it would be better not to create these objects every time the task is ran, but to keep them as `static` members.

This is how I was planning to do this:

1. The task is a `Service`, which is started in the `onCreate` method of an `Application` class
2. Once the `Service` is started, the heavy objects are initialized
3. When the task needs to be ran, `bindService` is called on the service

Is this a good way of doing this? Is there a better one?

Comment: Looks fine, just make sure the heavy task is run on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that a `Service` runs on the Main thread. So your scheme will not work as you wish. I would recommend you to create separate class which will create your objects.

```
public class HeavyObjectsHolder {

    private static volatile Object[] heavyObjects;

    public static Object[] get(){
        return heavyObjects;
    }

    public static void create(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //creation of heavy objects
                heavyObjects = new Object[]{
                    //populating array
                };
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I put that in my comment.